# Remember input data on page redirect

Tags: php, ajax, session, input, content-management-system

Before I begin the problem I faced, I would like to clarify what am I doing.

I have 2 pages.

1. restaurant.php
2. categories.php

Following screenshot is `restaurant.php`. You can see a button `Add Categories` under description and it will links to `categories.php`
[image]

Users will use the following steps to key in the info:

1. Fill in the title, description and upload the logo
2. They will click `Add Categories` button if they want to add some info
3. It will redirects to `categories.php` and users need to fill up the info on that page and click `save`
4. After saved, it will back to `restaurant.php`

Basically, what I want to do is retain the value entered by user on `restaurant.php` page after redirect from `categories.php`

---

Part of my simplified codes as shown below (ignore the upload image code for temporary)

restaurant.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])){
       $title=sanitize($_POST['title']);
       $description=sanitize_html($_POST['description']);

       mysql_query("UPDATE restaurant SET title='$title', description='$description' WHERE id='$id'");
    }
    else{
       $_SESSION['title'] = $_POST['title'];
       $_SESSION['description'] = $_POST['description'];
    }
?>   

<script>
     $('button').click(function() {
         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "categories.php",
          data: 'title='+ title,
          success: function(){
            location.reload();
          }
       });
    });
</script>

<form action="restaurant.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['title']; ?>">

    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea name="description" >
      <?php echo $_SESSION['description']; ?>
    </textarea>

    <button><a href="categories.php">Add Categories</a></button>

    <input class="button" name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
```

What I get is retain the value on page reload (on the same page) by using ajax, but I'm not sure how to retain the value after redirect to other page and back to the same page. I accept other methods, promise it works. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you have already done it, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What Problem Your Are Facing?

Comment: Nope, the result I got only retains the input after refresh the page (on the same page). But when I click the add categories button and save, the restaurant's inputs are not retained.

Comment: Try changing from `$_SESSION` to `$_COOKIE`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit_button'])){
           $title=sanitize($_POST['title']);
           $description=sanitize_html($_POST['description']);

           mysql_query("UPDATE restaurant SET title='$title', description='$description' WHERE id='$id'");
        }
        else{
        if (isset($_COOKIE['title']) && isset($_COOKIE['description'])) {
           $title = "value=".$_COOKIE['title'];
           $description = $_COOKIE['description'];
        }
        else {
            $title = "";
            $description = "";
        }

        }
    ?>  

    <form action="restaurant.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" <?php echo $title; ?>>

        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" ><?php echo $description; ?>
        </textarea>

       <button type="button" id="addcategory" onclick="keepData();">Add Categories</button>

        <input class="button" name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
    </form>


<script>

        function keepData(){
        var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
        var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
        createCookie('title', title, 1);
        createCookie('description', description, 1);
        window.location.href="categories.php";
        }

    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
    //console.log('Cookie created! - '+name );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this method before, not working for me. I have changed my code to <button><a href="categories.php">Add Categories</a></button>. It will links to categories page.

Comment: It make sense now.... I suggest you to make a popup instead of open the url. Change to `<a href="categories.php" target="_blank">Add Categories</a></button>`

Comment: Can't I link to a new page and retain the value?

Comment: Yes you can, just that why do you have 2 similar stuff? You're using ajax to post the data to category.php and redirecting to category.php.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really familiar on how to write jqeury. I tried window.location.href before, but still not working. What am I suppose to write?

Comment: Is it something wrong? There is no respond when I click the button. FYI: I need to read the data from database.

Comment: which button do you click? Add category or Save?

Comment: Add category button.

Comment: It should have navigate you to categories.php right?

Comment: Yes, it should. But when I click it, there is no respond.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120102/discussion-between-muthafury-and-eelyn).